# ArcGIS API GeoJson

Tags: api, geojson, dashboard, arcgis-online

I have two questions and hope someone can provide me with ideas or solutions.

1. How do I create a file adding each week’s data to create one table; appending records.
2. How do I convert string variable into numeric variable before or after import.

I am using GeoJson API to add this table to ArcGIS Online to use in the Operational Dashboard app.

I am using API from authoritative data which only offers weekly data. Once the API connects to ArcGIS Online, the new data overrides the existing data in the dashboard so there’s no historical data table to use or display in trend analysis.

**Question 1:**
Does anyone have a solution on how to save data from each week to create master dataset that can be used for trend analysis without having to type in each week’s data into separate excel file outside of ArcGIS Online?

Here's the API code:

https://healthdata.gov/resource/di4u-7yu6.geojson?fips=24003

{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type":"Feature","geometry":null,"properties":{"test_positivity_rate_pct_change_from_prev_week":"-0.006","pct_vents_used_covid_avg_last_7_days":null,"state":"MD","cases_last_7_days":"138","total_tests_pct_change_from_prev_week":"0.061","pct_inpatient_beds_used_abs_change_from_prev_week":"-0.003","confirmed_covid_hosp_per_100_beds_last_7_days":"0.806","pct_inpatient_beds_used_covid_abs_change_from_prev_week":"-0.006","pct_icu_beds_used_covid_abs_change_from_prev_week":"-0.001","cases_pct_change_from_prev_week":"-0.048","pct_inpatient_beds_used_covid_avg_last_7_days":"0.011","total_tests_per_100k_last_7_days":"304.885","fips":"24003","pct_icu_beds_used_abs_change_from_prev_week":"-0.002","deaths_pct_change_from_prev_week":null,"county":"Anne Arundel County, MD","deaths_last_7_days":"2","pct_fully_vacc_total_pop":"0.809","pct_icu_beds_used_avg_last_7_days":"0.794","deaths_per_100k_last_7_days":"0.345","test_positivity_rate_last_7_days":"0.03","confirmed_covid_hosp_last_7_days":"10.524","date":"2023-04-26T00:00:00.000","pct_vents_used_avg_last_7_days":null,"pct_fully_vacc_65_and_older":"0.95","fema_region":"3","pct_inpatient_beds_used_avg_last_7_days":"0.807","pct_icu_beds_used_covid_avg_last_7_days":"0.019","total_cases":"120978","total_positive_tests_last_7_days":"67","total_deaths":"1288","pct_vents_used_abs_change_from_prev_week":null,"suspected_covid_hosp_last_7_days":"85.539","suspected_covid_hosp_per_100_beds_pct_change_from_prev_week":"-0.117","confirmed_covid_hosp_per_100_beds_pct_change_from_prev_week":"-0.35","suspected_covid_hosp_per_100_beds_last_7_days":"6.549","total_tests_last_7_days":"1766","cases_per_100k_last_7_days":"23.825","pct_vents_used_covid_abs_change_from_prev_week":null}}], "crs" : { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } } }

This is how the imported data looks in a table in ArcGIS Online

[image]

**Question 2:**
When the API brings the data into ArcGIS Online some of the variables get converted into string  variables. How do I convert it back into numeric variable when using it in the Operational Dashboard ?